# Tool for Campagnolo Centaur bottom bracket

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools, campagnolo

What tool do I need to put this *Campagnolo Centaur* bottom bracket
into a bicycle frame?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These bottom brackets use the same tool as Campagnolo cassette lockrings.

EDIT: There are some cassette lockring tools that fit the splines but don't have room for the square axle. Pick one that has full size hole at the other end.

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. That would be this tool for instance: https://www.bike-components.de/en/Cyclus-Tools/Cassette-Removal-Tool-for-Campagnolo-Cassettes-p28627/ ?

Comment: Yes, that one should work

Comment: @Stücke use the genuine Campagnolo one: I don't think the Cyclus version has a big enough hole to go over the BB spindle

Comment: https://www.bike-components.de/de/Campagnolo/Kassettenabzieher-Innenlagerwerkzeug-UT-BB080-p1763/

Comment: https://www.bike-components.de/de/Cyclus-Tools/Innenlager-Werkzeug-fuer-Campagnolo-p28639/ also looks OK but cheaper than campagnolo, check description

Comment: Good point. The first tool may or may not be deep enough to contain the axle, the two others work for sure.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!